# Load all assemblies without NGEN

Tags: vb.net

I have an application that have many forms with Devexpress Controls.The problem is that there's a long delay when I open the forms for the first time , and this happens with all forms.
 I don't want to use NGEN , and I'm using a code to preload all assemblies on my login form.
 This is the code :

```
Public Sub DoPrecompile()
    For Each an As System.Reflection.AssemblyName In System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()
        Dim asmb As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(an)
        If Not asmb.GlobalAssemblyCache Then
            For Each type As Type In asmb.GetTypes()
                If Not type.IsInterface AndAlso Not type.IsGenericTypeDefinition Then
                    'must initiate only classes without static constractors
                    Dim ci As System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo = type.GetConstructor(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.[Static] Or System.Reflection.BindingFlags.[Public] Or System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic, Nothing, type.EmptyTypes, Nothing)
                    If ci = Nothing Then
                        For Each method As System.Reflection.MethodInfo In type.GetMethods(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly Or System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or System.Reflection.BindingFlags.[Public] Or System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or System.Reflection.BindingFlags.[Static])
                            If Not method.IsAbstract AndAlso Not method.IsGenericMethodDefinition AndAlso Not method.ContainsGenericParameters Then
                                System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(method.MethodHandle)
                            End If
                        Next

                        For Each prop As PropertyInfo In type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.[Public] Or BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.[Static])
                            For Each accessor As MethodInfo In prop.GetAccessors(True)
                                System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(accessor.MethodHandle)
                            Next
                        Next
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I run this code on my startup form , but I get an error on the line :

System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(accessor.MethodHandle)

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Abstract methods cannot be prepared

What can I do ?

Thank you !

Comment: What are you trying to use `.PrepareMethod` for?

Comment: Run the jitter.  The exception message explains it rather well.  Check MethodInfo.IsAbstract.  This is rather a bad way to solve the problem, it will greatly delay getting the app started.  Use Ngen.

Comment: I have my reasons to not using NGEN , for example I can't run NGEN on each user PC that get my Program.So , I thought to load all assemblies on a fixed point of execution , on my startup form.And after this delay I think the program will run faster.